# Rails - Link Facebook Account to authenticated User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth-facebook

I have a rails app with an authenticated user.

In his dashboard, i'd like to add a link : "Link my Facebook Profil".
Once he click on this link, he can login with his facebook account.

There is a lot of tutorial to login with facebook but no to just link an existing connected user with his facebook profil.

Anyone can give me a way to do that ?

Thank you.